# Effects in jQuery Overlay

Tags: jquery, overlay, effects

Can anyone say, How many effects are there in jQuery tools Overlay and what are they? 
 I searched in this link [effects list](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html#effects_list), shows nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/custom-effect.html) for an explanation, in any case i copy and paste here

> Custom Overlay effect Custom overlay effects are done with the
>   $.tools.overlay.addEffect method. The first argument is the effect
>   name, the second argument is the function that defines how the overlay
>   is shown and the third argument defines how the overlay closes. Inside
>   the functions the this variable is a reference to the overlay API.
>
> The loading function receives two arguments. The first argument css
>   defines the top and left properties given in the configuration. The
>   second argument is a callback function that must be called after you
>   have performed your loading effect.

```
// loading animation
$.tools.overlay.addEffect("drop", function(css, done) { 

   // use Overlay API to gain access to crucial elements
   var conf = this.getConf(),
       overlay = this.getOverlay();           

   // determine initial position for the overlay
   if (conf.fixed)  {
      css.position = 'fixed';
   } else {
      css.top += $(window).scrollTop();
      css.left += $(window).scrollLeft();
      css.position = 'absolute';
   } 

   // position the overlay and show it
   overlay.css(css).show();

   // begin animating with our custom easing
   overlay.animate({ top: '+=55',  opacity: 1,  width: '+=20'}, 400, 'drop', done);

   /* closing animation */
   }, function(done) {
      this.getOverlay().animate({top:'-=55', opacity:0, width:'-=20'}, 300, 'drop', function() {
         $(this).hide();
         done.call();      
      });
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are an unlimited number of effects as you can write your own..

See supplied link..

Making custom effects
If you want to make custom effects you should use the $.tools.overlay.addEffect method. This method is "static", meaning that you don't have to have the overlay API (or instance) already loaded. You can add effects before any overlays are initialized.